# Pull list of campaigns from Google Adwords API?

Tags: api, google-ads-api

The Google [Adwords API documentation](https://developers.google.com/s/results/?q=campaign%20id&p=%2Fadwords%2Fapi%2F) is super difficult to navigate.

I know I am missing something. How can I pull a list of the campaigns under a certain account? Is there a report that includes it or API call? I can use a list of IDs or names but I can't find either.

Comment: You can do that with the reports, CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT is perfect for you. Do you want to make it with a script or which API?

Comment: Adwords API. Does the CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT give a list of campaign IDs?

Comment: Of course, you can see all the fields of this report on: 
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Google's googleads github repo.

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201506/reporting/download_criteria_report.py

This is an example of downloading a criteria performance report.

1. Change reportType to CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT.
2. In the selector object, change fields to the fields you want out of the list - https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report
3. If you want to add an id filter then you need to add a predicates object to the selector that looks like:

   {'field': 'CampaignId', 'operator': 'IN', 'values': campaign_ids}

Not all fields in the campaign are available in the reporting section. In this case I would suggest to use the campaign service to download the campaigns. Keep in mind that this operation is slower than reporting.

Take a look at this example from the googleads repo - https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201506/basic_operations/get_campaigns.py

Comment: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201506/basic_operations/get_campaigns.py This link is not working. Please add the code instead of link